# Which flags to open a file the way Notepad.exe does?

Tags: c#, file-io

I'm writing a C# app to read a file that another application holds open. As some of you may guess, all I get is IOExceptions because "the file is being used by another process". I've tried tweaking File.Open() a little; this is my current try:

```
FileStream fsIn = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
```

(I know that the FileShare flag is more meaningful for other processes that *will* access the file thereafter, but I have tried with it anyway.)

What puzzles me is that Notepad.exe will open the file just fine. Before I dig into Filemon for more clues, does any of you know how to open the file the way Notepad does? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost have it.  You actually want `FileShare.ReadWrite`:

```
FileStream fsIn = File.Open(fileName,
                            FileMode.Open,
                            FileAccess.Read,
                            FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

`FileShare.Read` disallows other processes from writing to that file.  `FileShare.ReadWrite` allows this.

> **Write** Allows subsequent opening of
> the file for writing. If this flag is
> not specified, any request to open the
> file for writing (by this process or
> another process) will fail until the
> file is closed. However, even if this
> flag is specified, additional
> permissions might still be needed to
> access the file.
>
> **ReadWrite** Allows
> subsequent opening of the file for
> reading or writing. If this flag is
> not specified, any request to open the
> file for reading or writing (by this
> process or another process) will fail
> until the file is closed. However,
> even if this flag is specified,
> additional permissions might still be
> needed to access the file.

It's backwards to me as well.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you are dealing with small files, just use

```
string myFileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"c:\daniellesteele.txt");
```

for text or

```
byte[] myfileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\aleagueoftheirmoan.mpg");
```

for binary files.

Comment: tempted to give +1 for the mpg :P

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but this is the kind of file that starts small but may grow very big quickly!

Comment: yeah, then this is NOT the option for you.  Just throwing it out there for general information.  I love me some ReadAllText().  And you guys are right.  This answer definitely does not deserve a +1.  :P

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure Notepad can open the file *after* the other process has opened it? It looks like it's up to who initially owns the file if sharing is granted. See the following example from  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare%28VS.71%29.aspx):

```
The following FileStream constructor opens an existing file and grants read-only access to other users (FileShare.Read).

[C#] 
FileStream s2 = new FileStream(name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
```

Of course I'm not an OS expert, so this may be completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

With this

```
FileStream fsIn = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

you allow other programs modify the file, while its open in your program.
So, if you open the file, the IOException "the file is being used by another process" won't executed.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
FileStream file = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't behave any better! Thanks anyway.